# Use variable with ViewData Instead of literal string

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to use a variable in place of the string literal for ViewData?  What I have is this ...

```
var listsource = <% = ViewData["dtYears"] %>;
```

And what I'd like to do is something like this ...

```
var datasource = "dtYears";
var listsource = <% = ViewData[datasource] %>;
```

The reason I'd like do this so so I can have a generic function in my javascript that loads the list I specify with the datasource I specify (both via a parameter).  Then I can have a generic LoadList function like so ...

```
function LoadList(datasource, target) {
 // generic list population code goes here 
}
```

Comment: Is `datasource` a JavaScript variable?

Comment: Right datasource is just a javascript variable.  I basically want to assign the string value to that variable and then use the variable with ViewData, all on the client side.

Comment: Then you wont be able to that as JavaScript runs on client side and `ViewData` is controlled by ASP.Net engine. if `datasource` is ASP.Net variable you will be able to achieve that. You should look for some alternate strategies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
//On your server code(controller) where you set the ViewData
// Convert the datasource List/object to a json string and add the string to ViewData

ViewData["dtYears"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstYears);


//On your Client html code (view)
//convert it to equavalent json object/objects, using one of the following two methods

var datasource = eval("(" + '<%=ViewData["dtYears"].ToString() %>' + ")");

//OR use jquery method

var datasource =jQuery.parseJSON('<%=ViewData["dtYears"].ToString() %>');

//you should be good to go
alert(datasource.length+ " objects in "+ datasource );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I know that should work. Have you tried it and not gotten results you'd like?

Comment: In the example above, when I switch to the var named datasource instead of using a string, it's undefined.